# No repository for "myEntityName" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to create a simple nestjs REST api and for now I have connect the server to my database and create some entities. The server connects to the database successfully, but it can't my single created entity `TValue`, throwing the error from the title `No repository for "TValue" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection? at RepositoryNotFoundError.TypeORMError`.
This is my entity

```
@Entity()
export class TValue {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  value: number;

  @Column()
  boardId: string;
}
```

I tried following the nestjs [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database) for TypeORM integration, so I ended up with the following code for:

`tvalue.module.ts`

```
import {Module} from "@nestjs/common";
import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { TValueController } from "src/controllers/tvalue.controller";
import { TValue } from "../../entities/TValue.entity";
import { TValueService } from "./tvalue.service";

@Module({
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([TValue])],
    providers: [TValueService],
    controllers: [TValueController],
    exports: [TValueService]
})

export class TValueModule{}
```

and `app.module.ts`

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AppController } from '../controllers/app.controller';
import { AppService } from '../services/app.service';
import { Connection } from 'typeorm';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TValue } from '../entities/TValue.entity';
import { TValueController } from 'src/controllers/tvalue.controller';
import { TValueModule } from './tvalue/tvalue.module';
ConfigModule.forRoot();

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      url: process.env.TYPEORM_URL,
      entities: [
        TValue
      ],
      synchronize: process.env.ENV === "DEV" ? true : false,
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      // check aditional options for typeorm from nest
    }),
    TValueModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController, TValueController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private connection: Connection) {}
}
```

I won't include the `tvalue.service.ts` and `tvalue.controller.ts` since I think they are irrelevant here.
I have tried looking for a solution, found that I should give a name to my entity in the `@Entity('name')` decorator (tried with TValue and tvalue but it didn't work). Also tried playing with the way I [import the entities in `app.module.ts`](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3017) inside the `entities` array option, but again didn't work.
My folder structure, if it helps:

```
src/
   entities/
           TValue.entity.ts 
   modules/
          tvalue/
                tvalue.module.ts, tvalue.service.ts, app.module.ts
```

Hope the question is fine and thanks in advance!

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a `name` property in your `TypeOrmModule.forRoot()` would you?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel shouldn't the connection name be default since I haven't modified it?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to make sure of. Sometimes people will add a `name` property and you'll get this error